# Get response doesn't render in Angular 2 code

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to render a post request result. The backend is working fine. However, it is impossible to display the result like this:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [InvoiceService],
    template: `
        <div ng-if="invoice">
        <span>{{ invoice?.invoiceType | async }}</span>
        </div>
    `
})
```

There is probably a mistake in the code above. The request response is get asynchronously, but is seems that the "template" is rendered before the result is available - the html element is empty.

The rest of the code was checked carefully and seems to be working well, but might be important for understanding:

```
export class InvoiceDetail implements OnInit {
    private invoice: Invoice;
    private errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private invoiceService: InvoiceService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('On init invoice');
        this.getInvoice();
    }

    getInvoice() {
        const id: number = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
        this.invoiceService.getInvoice(id).subscribe(
            (invoiceResp: Invoice) => this.invoice = invoiceResp);

        console.log("Id: " + id);
    }

}
```

The invoice class:

```
export class Invoice {
    constructor(
        public invoiceNumber: string,
        public creationDate: string,
        public invoiceType: string
    ) { }
}
```

The service methods:

```
 getInvoice(id:number): Observable<Invoice> {
    return this.http.get(this.invoiceUrl+id)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body || {};
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
```

Any ideas and suggestions will be very appreciated.

EDIT:
This is the rendered html element (I changed ng-if to *ngIf)

```
<ng-component>
        <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><div>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</ng-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template should use **`*ngIf`** not **`ng-if`**,

```
<div *ngIf="invoice">
        <span>{{ invoice?.invoiceType | async }}</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help. The field is not rendered.

Comment: I added the html element that is rendered, at the end of the question